# How to invoke shell script as engineering user from java code

Tags: java

```
  final String[] cmdArray = {
 "/bin/bash", "/var/tmp/invoke_payment_files_generator.sh",
 String.valueOf(paymentBatchId)
 };


 final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray); 

processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

above code works for me but is their a way to invoke this shell script as a engineering user instead of unix user from java code.Can anyone suggest the way and can anyone suggest how to know by which user shell script is being invoked from java code

Comment: What do you mean by "engineering user"?

Comment: `engineering user instead of unix user` - hear of unix / windows /mac users....whats this new breed of users(*engineering*)!!!!!??? :o

Comment: If you use it that way, the shell will be run under the user that started the JVM. There are ways to have have commands invoked under a specific user (and it is easy under Unix thanks to set-user_id), but you should thing of the security implications.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sudo to run the script as another user. If the path is fixed, just add this to your sudoers file:

```
<jvmuser> ALL=(<execuser>) NOPASSWD: "/bin/bash /var/tmp/invoke_payment_files_generator.sh"
```

Replace  with the shelluser and  with the user running the java command.

Then modify your java shell command to run this:

```
sudo -u <execuser> /bin/bash /var/tmp/invoke_payment_files_generator.sh
```

It is untested and may need some tweaks, but the general idea should work just fine.

---

Another approach would just call a API (unix domain socket, web-servlet, file, sql queue table, rpc, etc.) which in return runs the payment file generator script for you, if you do not need the output.